django rest framework can't set an attribute when get_or_create
I have a model with a constraint defined:
class Spender(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True,default=uuid.uuid4,editable=False)
    first_name = models.CharField("FirstName", max_length=240, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField("LastName", max_length=240, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    authUserId = models.IntegerField(unique=True, null=True)
    friends = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True, symmetrical=False)

    class meta:
        constraints = [models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['email'], name='spender_unq')]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

I have also defined a serializer with the create method:
class SpenderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Spender 
        read_only_fields = ['id', 'created','authUserId']
        fields = ['id', 'first_name','last_name', 'email', 'authUserId']

    def validate(self, attrs):
        validated_attrs = super().validate(attrs)
        errors = {}
        if (
            self.instance
            and 'email' in validated_attrs
            and self.instance.name != validated_attrs['email']
        ):
            if (
                Spender.objects.filter(email=validated_attrs['email'])
                .exclude(id=self.instance.id)
                .exists()
            ):
                errors['email'] = self.error_messages['email_exists']

        if errors:
            raise ValidationError(errors)

        return validated_attrs
    
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        authUserId = None

        try:
            user = User.objects.get(email=validated_data.get("email"))
            authUserId = user.get('id')
            validated_data['authUserId']=authUserId
        except:
            pass

        return Spender.objects.get_or_create(**validated_data, defaults={'authUserId': authUserId})[0]

This is the view:
class SpenderCreate(generics.CreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

    queryset = Spender.objects.all(),
    serializer_class = SpenderSerializer

When I post a new spender record
{"last_name":"John", "first_name":"Doe", "email":"johndoew@gmail.com"}

the server returns spender with an empty authUserId
{"id":"6b9ac5fd-e592-461a-a8dc-17e8b90103b0","first_name":"Doe","last_name":"John","email":"djohndoew@gmail.com","authUserId":null}


When I execute a query to the user table
select * from public.auth_user where email = 'djohndoew@gmail.com' 

a row with the user data exists:
last_login|is_superuser|username|first_name|last_name|email              |is_staff|
----------+------------+--------+----------+---------+-------------------+--------+
          |false       |djohndoe|John      |Doe      |djohndoew@gmail.com|false   |

What is wrong with the create method?
I also this approach, but I think there is something wrong with the validated data:
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(email=validated_data.get("email"))
        authUserId = user.get('id')
        #validated_data['authUserId']=authUserId
    except:
        pass

    return Spender.objects.get_or_create(authUserId=authUserId, **validated_data)[0]


The problem was that User is a class object, not a dictionary, and a cunstruction authUserId = user.get('id') must be like authUserId = user.id. Try-except without raise made this situation incomprehensible
